# Managing large list in SharePoint 2013 OnPremise

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 On Premise site. I have to create a main list which can have 4000 items in it. There will be 4 more list which are relational to this main list. Each item in main list can have 12+ items in the relational list. I want to understand how do I create Folder structure for this to avoid threshold issue. I will have to create report on this data.

**For Example:** 
I have a main list called Project. And Sub list called Tasks. For each project there can be 15 tasks. How do I create folder structure on the Tasks list based on Project ID? One folder for each  Project ID? Or a folder named "1000" , "2000" that will contain tasks for project ID ranging from 1 to 1000 and 1001 to 2000 respectively.

Also, please give me pointers on reporting as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either by naming the folder by the ProjectID or you could take the Year of its creation. In this Year Folder you also could have subfolders for the months.

Comment: Does SharePoint have limit to the number of folder that can be created at root level or number of folders that can be created inside a folder? Since if i create the folder by Project id there can be 4000+ folders at the root level.

Comment: idk about a limit, bu i guess its the same as documents (?). And the number of Folders inside a folder should be the same as the number of possible folders on the root level.

Comment: SharePoint's list view threshold is a per-view (and hence, per container) restriction; you could have up to 5000 folders per level without running into the list view threshold. However, you'll still run into the restrictions imposed on any list that surpasses 5000 items; for example, you won't be able to apply column indexing, create or modify calculated columns, or delete the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a folder structure for this requirement. Instead, you will want to apply column indexing on the lookup column(s) you use to relate the lists to one another.

After a list has surpassed the list view threshold (5000 items by default) you will be unable to sort and filter by any **unindexed** columns. You can still sort/filter by indexed columns. Essentially, SharePoint keeps a sorted index of that column that it can use to quickly jump to a specific item or set of items, in the same way that you could quickly find a specific book on a shelf when the books are arranged in alphabetical order.

Column indexing can be added to columns from the list settings menu.